# How do you convert a dmg file to img in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I have installed dmg2img-1.6.2 on my Virtual Computer. when I say installed I mean I can see the folder dmg2img-1.6.2 and contents in my home directory. I am using linux 12.04. I have been trying for a week now to convert a dmg file to img using terminal. The response to "dmg2img lightroom_5_LS11.dmg" is syntax error. Other commands usually respond as " cannot open input file lightroom _5_LS11.dmg. Any help would be appreciated. Not sure which set of commands to use. Just been using trial and error method, none of which has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DMG2IMG.

To install, Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

To use, just do `dmg2img -i <input.dmg> -o <output.img>`  See [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/dmg2img.1.html)

Comment: I have tried this command...I just get syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried it like this? Example: `dmg2img /user/home/downloads/test.dmg -o test.img`.  You have to include the path to the .dmg file.

Comment: does "test" also mean something else? Or do I actually type test?

Comment: instead of test you input your file name.

Comment: The response is "Can't open input file /parallels/home/downloads/lightroom.dmg". This is what I keep getting no matter which set of commands I use. Do you know why?

Comment: You just have to figure out the correct path.

Comment: The file is in home/downloads, there is also a copy in home/documents, neither of these paths work. Do I need to state the working directory first by typing" cd downloads"?

Comment: if you do, then you can `dmg2img test.dmg test.img`

Comment: My terminal directory now says "parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/Downloads$ then I typed "dmg2img lightroom.dmg lightroom.img". But the response is still "ERROR: Can't open input file lightroom.dmg" What can the problem be?

Comment: It sounds that you .dmg file is corrupt.  Do you have a different file that you can try with?  I use the command 2 -3 times a week, and have no issues with it.

Comment: I have downloaded the file again and still the same result. Do you think it is because it is a BIN file type 501MB?

Comment: Try `dd if=lightroom.bin of=lightroom.img`

Answer (score 0):

Move your file to your *HOME DIRECTORY* and after this use `dmg2img -i lightroom.dmg -o lightroom.img`

After this you can find your *lightroom.img* in your *HOME DIRECTORY*

I think you see problem with path because you have not English Ubuntu.